# Authenticity and meaning of the hadith, of black jinn riding the Prophet Muhammad ? (saw)

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Salaam alaikum,

Can you please translate and explain the meaning of this hadith. Supposedly naked black jinn riding the prophet Muhammad (saw). Also what is the authenticity of this narration.

Link in Arabic below. Thank you.

https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&flag=1&bk_no=87&ID=14109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hadith is about the event when the Prophet ﷺ recited the Quran to the Jinn. Nearly all of the content of the hadith is present in [Jami' at-Tirmidhi 2861](https://sunnah.com/urn/730940) which is translated so you can refer to that.

As for the part about "riding" it is the statement:

> فأتوا فجعلوا يركبون رسول الله

This is an idiom to express that the Jinn were crowded around the prophet, eager to listen to the Quran.

> [image]
>
> <sup>— [Lane's Lexicon](https://archive.org/details/dli.granth.94260/page/1142/mode/2up)</sup>

The same is conveyed by the verse of the Quran:

> وأنه لما قام عبد الله يدعوه كادوا يكونون عليه لبدا
>
> And that when the Servant of Allah stood up supplicating Him, they almost became about him a compacted mass.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 72:19](http://quran.com/72/19)</sup>

And without using an idiom in the hadith of al-Bayhaqi through a different chain:

> فازدحموا عليه
>
> <sup>— [Dalail al-Nubuwwah](https://al-maktaba.org/book/7478/754#p1)</sup>

As for the authenticity of the particular chain in the question, it has been classed as Sahih by some such as [Shakir](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33037/1711)  and Da'eef by others such as [al-Arnaa’oot](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/2820) , because there are varying reports on whether Amr al-Bakali (عمرو البكالي) was a Sahabi or a Tabi and whether he learnt hadith from Abdullah Ibn Masud.